# Nexus 7 - USB Port & Headphone Socket

Tags: usb, audio, nexus-7, headphone-jack

I sometimes experience a drop in sound in the left or right earphone of my headphones when charging my Nexus 7.

Wiggling the usb cable in the port can bring back the sound, however yesterday the sound was coming out of the left earbud only while not being charged. I took a micro usb cable and wiggled it around until audio was restored to both sound channels.

Has anyone experienced this issue that seems to tie the usb port to the headphone socket audio output?